# degree of homogeneity

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, multivariable-calculus

I have the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{y^b}{x^a}+\frac{x^b}{y^a}\quad a,b\gt0$$

The questions I have to answer are

1. For which a and b is the function homogenous?
2. Determine the degree of homogeneity

My steps are as follows:

$$\frac{(λy)^b}{(λx)^a} + \frac{(λx)^b}{(λy)^a} = \frac{(λy)^{b+a}+(λx)^{ba}}{λ^2xy}$$

Im not sure how to go from here. I would appreciate if someone could help me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That second equality doesn't make sense to me.  Try this:

$$f(\lambda x,\lambda y) = \lambda^{b-a} \Bigl( \frac{y^b}{x^a} + \frac{x^b}{y^a} \Bigr).$$

So $f$ is homogeneous for all values of $a,b$, with the degree of homogeneity equal to $b-a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(tx,ty)=t^{b-a}\frac{y^b}{x^a}+t^{b-a}\frac{x^b}{y^a}= t^kf(x,y)$$ for $k=b-a$.